# change a variable value using *ngIf in angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to add some validation using [pattern] in an angular 7 application. I want to disable a button using a variable `this.isSubmitDisabled` if the pattern has errors ( `phoneNumber.errors?.pattern` ).

I know that this can be achieved using Reactive form but unfortunately, I cannot use forms. Is there a way to set the variable value to 'true' if `phoneNumber.errors?.pattern` is `true`?.

Here is my code:

```html
<input 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  (ngModelChange)="dialInDetailsChange($event)" 
  name="dialInDetails" 
  [disabled]="false" 
  id="dialInDetails" 
  pattern="^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?$" 
  required 
  [(ngModel)]="agendaMeeting.dialInDetails" 
  ngModel #dialInDetails="ngModel" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check it using `.match()` in your `.ts` file. On model change just check whether the entered value matches your `regex`. If matches then set `inputDisabled` to `false` otherwise set `inputDisabled` to `true`.

```
let inputDisabled:boolean = false;
dialInDetailsChange(event:any){
  if(agendaMeeting.dialInDetails.match("^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?$") === null){
    inputDisabled = true;
  }
  else{
    inputDisabled = false;
  }
}
```

> Edit after recent comment

**WORKING DEMO** : [LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jkdq3)

```
myInput='';
result='';
  changeHandler(){
    if(this.myInput.match('^[\\s]+[a-zA-Z]*')  === null){
      this.result = "correct input";
    }
    else{
      this.result = "there are spaces at the begining."
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Himanshu, I used your logic and got it to work. I have removed the pattern from HTML and am only using regex in the ts file. I am looking for a regex to allow everything except blank spaces at the start of the input and I am using ^\s*$ for that. Unfortunately something is not working. Here is my condition

if (this.agendaMeeting.dialInDetails.match(/^\s*$/g) === null) {
      this.isSubmitDisabled = true;
    };

Answer (score 0):

i think ***you can't assign values*** using expression in your template, check the documentations

```
You can't use JavaScript expressions that have or promote side effects, including:
```

- Assignments (=, +=, -=, ...)
- Operators such as new, typeof, instanceof, etc.
- Chaining expressions with ; or ,
- The increment and decrement operators ++ and --
- Some of the ES2015+ operators

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  (ngModelChange)="updateState(phone)" 
  name="dialInDetails" 
  [disabled]="false" 
  id="dialInDetails" 
  pattern="^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?$" 
  required 
  [(ngModel)]="agendaMeeting.dialInDetails" 
  #phone="ngModel" />    

<button type="button" [disabled]="isDisabled">Submit</button>


updateState(input){
    this.isDisabled = input.errors && input.errors.pattern ? true : false ;
  }
```